# Netsuite 1.0 - Gift Certificate Sublist Values

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I am working on a suitelet that pulls gift cards with a value and displays the sender, receiver, date, original and available amounts. After I got that working I wanted to expand it to including the order number and when it was last used to determine dormancy. I can't seem to figure out how to get the sublist values though from the "Transactions" listing(s).

```
//SUITELET SCRIPT

var objResults = {};
var linkColor = '#255599';

function checkMethod(request, response)
{
    var form = nlapiCreateForm('GiftCards With Balance');

    if(request.getMethod() == 'GET') {
        buildForm(form, request);
    }
    else {
        buildForm(form, request);
    }
    response.writePage(form);
}

function buildForm(form, request)
{
    //REMOVING BUTTONS UNLESS THEY SHOULD BECOME NECESSARY
    form.addButton('custpage_refresh', 'Refresh', 'window.onbeforeunload = null; location.href = '
        + 'nlapiResolveURL(\'SUITELET\', \'customscript_ls_gc_customer_balance_sl\', \'customdeploy_ls_gc_customer_balance_sl\');');
        
    //QUERY GIFT
    queryGiftCerts();

    createSublist(form);
    addToSublist(form);
}

function createSublist(form)
{
    var sublist = form.addSubList('giftcertificate', 'list', 'Results (' + Object.keys(objResults).length + ')');
    sublist.addField('purchasedate', 'date', 'Purchase Date');
    sublist.addField('sender', 'text', 'Sender Name'); 
    sublist.addField('name', 'text', 'Recipient Name'); 
    sublist.addField('ordernumber', 'text', 'Order #');
    sublist.addField('giftcertcode', 'text', 'Gift Certificate Code'); 
    sublist.addField('originalamount', 'currency', 'Original Purchase Amount');
    sublist.addField('amountremaining', 'currency', 'Amount Remaining');
    sublist.addField('lastused', 'date', 'Last Used');
}

function addToSublist(form)
{
    var keys = Object.keys(objResults);
    for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        var giftcertID = keys[i];
        var key = objResults[giftcertID];

        var line = (i + 1);
        var sublist = form.getSubList('giftcertificate');

        sublist.setLineItemValue('purchasedate', line, key.gcPurchaseDate);
        sublist.setLineItemValue('sender', line, key.gcSender); 
        sublist.setLineItemValue('name', line, key.gcRecipient); 
        sublist.setLineItemValue('ordernumber', line, key.gcOrderNumber);
        sublist.setLineItemValue('originalamount', line, key.gcOriginalAmount);
        sublist.setLineItemValue('giftcertcode', line, key.giftCertHTML); 
        sublist.setLineItemValue('amountremaining', line, key.gcAmountRemaining);
        sublist.setLineItemValue('lastused', line, key.gcLastUsed);
    }
}

function queryGiftCerts()
{
    var filters = new Array();
    filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('amountremaining', null, 'greaterthan', '0.00'));
    filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('purchasedate', null, 'between', '1/1/2001','12/31/2018'));
    filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter('gcactive', null, 'is', 'T'));

    var columns = new Array();
    columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('internalId'));
    columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('purchasedate').setSort(false));
    columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('sender'));
    columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('name'));
    columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('ordernumber'))
    columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('originalamount'));
    columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('giftcertcode'));
    columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('amountremaining'));
    columns.push(new nlobjSearchColumn('lastused'));

    var searchid = 0;
    var savedSearch = nlapiCreateSearch('giftcertificate', filters, columns);
    var resultset = savedSearch.runSearch();

    do {
        var searchResults = resultset.getResults(searchid, searchid + 1000);
        if(searchResults && searchResults.length > 0) {
            for(var i = 0; i < searchResults.length; i++) {
                var giftcertID = searchResults[i].getId();
                var gcItemID = searchResults[i].getValue('internalId')
                var gcSender = searchResults[i].getValue('sender');
                var gcRecipient = searchResults[i].getValue('name');
                var gcOrder = searchResults[i].getValue('')
                var gcOriginalAmount = searchResults[i].getValue('originalamount');
                var gcCode = searchResults[i].getValue('giftcertcode');
                var gcAmountRemaining = searchResults[i].getValue('amountremaining');
                var gcPurchaseDate = searchResults[i].getValue('purchasedate');

                //LINK GENERATION
                //CONSTRUCT URL HYPERLINK FOR COMMODITY
                var giftCertHTML = '<a style="text-decoration:none; color:' + linkColor + '" '
                    + 'href=/app/accounting/transactions/giftcertificaterecord.nl'
                    + '?id=' + gcItemID + ' target=_blank>' + gcCode + '</a>';
                  
               //ADD ORDER TO OBJECT
               if(!objResults[giftcertID]) {
                  objResults[giftcertID] = {};
                  objResults[giftcertID].gcItemID = gcItemID;
                  objResults[giftcertID].gcSender = gcSender;
                  objResults[giftcertID].gcRecipient = gcRecipient;
                  objResults[giftcertID].gcOriginalAmount = gcOriginalAmount;
                  objResults[giftcertID].gcCode = gcCode;
                  objResults[giftcertID].gcAmountRemaining = gcAmountRemaining;
                  objResults[giftcertID].gcPurchaseDate = gcPurchaseDate;
                  objResults[giftcertID].giftCertHTML = giftCertHTML;
                }
            
                if (i == searchResults.length) {
                    return; 
                }
            }

            searchid += searchResults.length;
        }
        
    } while (searchResults && searchResults.length >= 1000);
}
```